# this code is working correctly in android 2.2 but not working android 2.3 and above

Tags: android, android-webview

```
WebView browser;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        browser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webve);


        browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        browser.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJavaScriptInterface(), "HTMLOUT");
        browser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
            {
                browser.loadUrl("javascript:window.HTMLOUT.showHTML('<head>'+document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML+'</head>');");

            }

        });


        browser.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
    }

    final Context myApp = this;
    Builder builder;

    String content_html;

    class MyJavaScriptInterface
    {
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        public void showHTML(String html)
        {
           builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(myApp);
                builder.setTitle("HTML")
                .setMessage(html)
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null)
            .setCancelable(false)
            .create()
            .show();
                content_html = html;
                Log.i("html", html+" ");
        }

    }
```

this code is working correctly in android 2.2 but not working android 2.3 and above... Giving error message that displayed below..

```
12-19 14:53:33.786: W/dalvikvm(452): JNI WARNING: jarray 0x40543998 points to non-array object (Ljava/lang/String;)
    12-19 14:53:33.831: I/dalvikvm(452): "WebViewCoreThread" prio=5 tid=9 NATIVE
    12-19 14:53:33.838: I/dalvikvm(452):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x4051e198 self=0x29b650
    12-19 14:53:33.838: I/dalvikvm(452):   | sysTid=460 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=2733960
    12-19 14:53:33.858: I/dalvikvm(452):   | schedstat=( 2873090555 2669702962 182 )
    12-19 14:53:33.878: I/dalvikvm(452):   at android.webkit.BrowserFrame.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString(Native Method)
    12-19 14:53:33.885: I/dalvikvm(452):   at android.webkit.BrowserFrame.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString(Native Method)
    12-19 14:53:33.905: I/dalvikvm(452):   at android.webkit.BrowserFrame.loadUrl(BrowserFrame.java:246)
    12-19 14:53:33.924: I/dalvikvm(452):   at android.webkit.WebViewCore.loadUrl(WebViewCore.java:1570)
    12-19 14:53:33.924: I/dalvikvm(452):   at android.webkit.WebViewCore.access$1400(WebViewCore.java:53)
    12-19 14:53:33.934: I/dalvikvm(452):   at android.webkit.WebViewCore$EventHub$1.handleMessage(WebViewCore.java:956)
    12-19 14:53:33.955: I/dalvikvm(452):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    12-19 14:53:33.955: I/dalvikvm(452):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
    12-19 14:53:33.955: I/dalvikvm(452):   at android.webkit.WebViewCore$WebCoreThread.run(WebViewCore.java:629)
    12-19 14:53:33.955: I/dalvikvm(452):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
    12-19 14:53:33.964: E/dalvikvm(452): VM aborting
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jason Shah explains everything in [this post](http://quitenoteworthy.blogspot.com/2010/12/handling-android-23-webviews-broken.html):

> Handling Android 2.3 WebView's broken AddJavascriptInterface
>
> (Apologies in advance to my normal readers for this technical topic.)
>
> The Google Android team released the Android 2.3 ("Gingerbread") SDK
>   two days ago, to much fanfare. This has sent the tech blogging world
>   into a publishing frenzy, as it usually does. However, a potentially
>   disastrous bug has surfaced that could crash literally thousands of
>   apps in the Android Market immediately after opening the app.
>
> The problem is described succintly here:
>   http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=12987 In short: Many
>   apps show all or part of their UI with embedded WebViews that can
>   render HTML. Those WebViews make use of a great feature that bridges
>   JavaScript (in the HTML) to the native Java code that "surrounds" the
>   WebView. This bridge is completely broken in Android 2.3. Trying to
>   make even a basic call breaks the WebView immediately and crashes the
>   app.
>
> I believe members of the Android team are aware of the problem, and
>   from early reports, it does not affect the Nexus S (the first Android
>   2.3 phone). This doesn't really help those of us working against the emulator, however.